# I am trying to create a custom user in my Django application but I am facing some Unknown problem when I tried my custom user

Tags: python, django

##My django codes are:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
# Register your models here.


from .models import MyUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label="password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', "email", "first_name", "last_name",
                  "gender", "date_of_birth")

        def clean_password2(self):
            password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
            if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
                raise ValidationError("Password don't match")
            return password2

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super().save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    passwrod = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', "email", "first_name", "last_name",
                  "gender", "date_of_birth", 'is_active', "is_admin")

        def clean_password(self):
            return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name',
                    'last_name', 'is_admin', 'is_active')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            "fields": ('username', 'email', 'first_name',
                       'last_name', 'is_admin', 'is_active', 'password', 'date_of_birth', 'gender'),
        }),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            "fields": ('username', 'email', 'first_name',
                       'last_name', 'is_admin', 'is_active', 'password1', 'password2', 'date_of_birth', 'gender'),
        }),
    )

    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


User = get_user_model()
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

##my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


# Create your models here.

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, first_name, last_name,  date_of_birth, gender,  password=None):
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a last name")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not gender:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a gender")
        if not date_of_birth:
            raise ValueError("You Must Enter your date of birth")

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
            gender=gender,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, first_name, last_name,  date_of_birth, gender,  password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            date_of_birth,
            gender,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender_choices = [
        ("male", "Male"),
        ("female", "Female"),
        ("others", "Others")
    ]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=gender_choices)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name',
                       'email', 'last_name',  'date_of_birth', 'gender']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

#MY urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users', views.userList, name="users"),
    path('login', views.logIn, name="login"),
    path('login-admin', views.adminLogin, name="login-admin"),
    path("register", views.registerUser, name="register")
]
```

#my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .form import AddForm
from .models import AddProduct, Order, OrderItem, Clint
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.


# @login_required
def index(request):
    allProduct = AddProduct.objects.count()
    lowOnStock = AddProduct.objects.filter(
        product_quantity__lte=5, product_quantity__gt=0).count()
    user = get_user_model()
    print(user.email)
    outOfStock = AddProduct.objects.filter(product_quantity=0).count()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"allProduct": allProduct, "los": lowOnStock, "oos": outOfStock, "user": user})


# @login_required
def productList(request):
    march = AddProduct.objects.all()
    return render(request, "productList.html", {"march": march})


# @login_required
def addProduct(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "addProduct.html", {"form": AddForm()})
    else:
        form = AddForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return redirect("/productList")


# @login_required
def deleteProduct(request, pk):
    delProduct = AddProduct.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        delProduct.delete()
        return redirect("/productList")
    else:
        return render(request, "delConform.html", {"item": delProduct})


# @login_required
def updateProduct(request, pk):
    upProduct = AddProduct.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = AddForm(instance=upProduct)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=upProduct)
        upProduct.img.delete()
        form .save()
        return redirect("/")
    return render(request, "updateProduct.html", {"form": form})


# @login_required
def addInfo(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        context = {}
        searchInput = request.GET.get("searchInput")
        if searchInput == None:
            context['products'] = AddProduct.objects.all()
        else:
            context['products'] = AddProduct.objects.filter(
                product_name__icontains=searchInput)
        context["orders"] = Order.objects.all()
        context["orderItems"] = OrderItem.objects.all()
        context["customers"] = Clint.objects.all()
        return render(request, "management.html", context)
```

Note: when I tried to print the user for checking purpose I got the unknown object <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000019720E0CDC0>

```
def index(request):
    allProduct = AddProduct.objects.count()
    lowOnStock = AddProduct.objects.filter(
        product_quantity__lte=5, product_quantity__gt=0).count()
    user = get_user_model()
    print(user.email)
    outOfStock = AddProduct.objects.filter(product_quantity=0).count()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"allProduct": allProduct, "los": lowOnStock, "oos": outOfStock, "user": user})
```

`user = get_user_model() print(user.email)`
I don't user.email insted I got this unknown object <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000019720E0CDC0>

Comment: Try `user = get_user_model().objects.first().email`

Comment: Thanks man I am new at python and django so I didn't know about this it worked perfectly

Comment: @NurulHafizLikhon if the question is solved, consider adding an answer with solution and accepting it, this helps to sort solved and unsolved questions.

Answer (score 0):

#I tried to solved the object #<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000019720E0CDC0> By putting it into user variable and
calling its fields but it didn't work like:

```
def index(request):
    allProduct = AddProduct.objects.count()
    lowOnStock = AddProduct.objects.filter(
        product_quantity__lte=5, product_quantity__gt=0).count()
    user = get_user_model()
    print(user.email)
    outOfStock = AddProduct.objects.filter(product_quantity=0).count()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"allProduct": allProduct, "los": lowOnStock, "oos": outOfStock, "user": user})

   user = get_user_model() print(user.email) I don't user.email insted I got this unknown object <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000019720E0CDC0>
```

`user = get_user_model() print(user.email)`
I didn't get the printed result insted i got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000019720E0CDC0> this object

but the I tried to add .first() ofter get_user_model
it worked I got my result

```
    user = get_user_model().first()
    print(user.email)
```

So try to use the .first() after model if you are facing this kind of problem